# Update Text Box On change Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to update a text box when a selection changes.

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#name").change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var result = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    document.getElementById('newname').value = result ;
});
</script>
```

Being an extream noob to this i dont understand why this is not working?
The #name is the dropdown list "selection" and the newname is the text box i want to update.

Comment: Where are you using `selectedValue` ? You are assigning it but not using it anywhere. Replace `string` with `selectedaValue` and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the var result, string.substring, do you mean selectedValue.substring ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#name").change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var result = selectedValue.substring(selectedValue.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    document.getElementById('newname').value = result ;
});
</script>
```

Comment: UGH! Yes that totally makes since! Thank you so much for your help on that one! been at that for almost 2 hours!

Comment: @KellyHansen no worries :)